# Tracker-miner-fs keeps crashing on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dbus, tracker, sqlite

I'm managing a fleet of 25 Ubuntu 22.04 systems. On one of them (possibly more I haven't discovered yet), tracker-miner-fs keeps crashing, and I can't figure out how to get control of that.

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with all the latest updates installed. Tracker is version 3.3.0-1

I only have command-line access to these systems by SSH, since the actual systems are 60 miles away. Access to the physical console is not a practical option.

I find these kinds of entries in /var/log/syslog:

```
Nov 17 09:32:24 bec315dl06 tracker-miner-f[6049]: SQLite error: database disk image is malformed (errno: Success)
Nov 17 09:32:24 bec315dl06 tracker-miner-f[6049]: message repeated 131 times: [ SQLite error: database disk image is malformed (errno: Success)]
```

The general recommendation for this problem is "tracker3 reset -s". However, that errors out:

```
~# tracker3 reset -s

(tracker reset:6269): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:03:26.952: g_dbus_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(tracker reset:6269): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:03:26.952: g_dbus_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(tracker reset:6269): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:03:26.952: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Found 0 PIDs…
```

tracker3 status also errors out:

```
~# tracker3 status
Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

That is not completely surprising, since I'm using an SSH connection.

At this point, I'm lost. I am not very familiar with the intricacies of D-Bus.

Is there a way to reset tracker manually, and would that fix all the problems, or would it just bypass some D-Bus issues that should also be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial answer.

Since tracker3 reset -s is not working, the way to repair the tracker database is as follows:

- kill the tracker-miner-fs-3 process.
- delete the SQLite database in /var/lib/gdm/.cache/tracker3
- Reboot the system.
- Confirm in /var/log/syslog that tracker3 no longer reports SQLite errors (there may be messages regarding a missing file).

There are additional tracker databases for each user in $HOME/.cache/tracker3 . In my case, the home directories are on an NFS share, which of course increases the risk of corruption.

The problems with tracker3 reset -s and tracker3 status still exist.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this - would you provide a better answer, or at least explain why you downvoted this?

Comment: I upvoted your question and answer because sometimes they give you a downvote and do not explain why ...